# Excel Custom Cell Format, Wildcard for Both Numbers and Text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I know of a custom format for text to add parenthesizes:

(@)

[example, "something" becomes "(something)"]

And I know one for numbers:

(0)

[example, "15" becomes "(15)"]

Is there a wildcard character for both text and numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them with a semicolon, as in `(0);(@)`. This also works with the `TEXT` function - just enclose the format within quote marks.

Comment: If nothing better exists, I guess this is the way to go. I just noticed this does not work if it is in a different order as "(@);(0)". Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, there are actually four parts of a custom format that Excel will recognize: a part for positive numbers, one for negative numbers, one for zeroes, and one for text.  If only one part is given, then it is applied to all numbers. Text always has to come last. Neat trick that is actually sometimes useful: ";;;" will show as nothing!